# Model calibration in overfitted models

Tags: predictive-models, model-selection, overfitting, calibration

Why in Shrinkage, due to an overfitted prediction model, do we tend to overestimate risk for "high risk" subjects and to underestimate risk for "low risk" subjects ?
Intuitively I would expect an error in both directions due to poor calibration for the model overfitted on data.

Comment: So I guess it's related to laplace rule of succession https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession ( under uniform prior on p, we estimate p as (s+1)/(n+2)

Comment: @seanv507 Can you be a little more detailed ? I'was not referring to Bayesan statistics in particular tbh.